# @synthesize in Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

test.h

```
NSString *name;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *name;
```

test.m

```
@synthesize name;
```

here why did we use ***nonatomic*** , **retain**  in the property and in .m file why we are using ***@synthesize*** ?

please answer ,

Comment: Your title doesn't match your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nonatomic` means that setting the property is not thread-safe, `retain` means new value is retained (and the old value released), and the `@synthesize` actually creates the methods that are necessary for the property. In this case, it evaluates to something like this:

```
- (NSString *)name {
    // Method "name", returning content of variable "name".
    return name;
}

- (void)setName:(NSString *)newName {
    [newName retain];
    [name release];
    name = newName;
    // Also some magic for KVO is added here.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html)

***nonatomic*** is described in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/objective-c-properties-atomic-vs-nonatomic).

***retain*** means that the property is retained when the value is set to anything other than nil. There are other options such as **copy** and  **assign**. Normally object types that can be copied should use **copy**, like `NSString`. **assign** simply sets the pointer value.

***@synthesize*** stubs out the getter and setter methods for the property and is required in order for the **nonatomic** and **retain** to work.

Also, make sure that if you use **retain** or  **copy**, that you also **release** the object in the `dealloc` method.

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [name release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: `nonatomic` doesn't have much to do with thread safety. It just means that you'll always get a viable value in a threaded environment. Whether it is right or not is not guaranteed (i.e. atomicity is not a transaction system).

Comment: Good post, but why would you want to `copy` objects when you don't really have to ? Especially if you're using immutable objects (like NSString) copying is only a waste of memory. I very rarely found the need for `copy` so far.

Comment: @DarkDust: Every NSMutableString is a valid NSString. You don't want to accidentally store one of those and have it change under you. Most objects that implement copy at least *could* be mutable. Therefore, it's a good idea to declare all properties that way. Also, as an optimization, NSString (the immutable version) merely retains when you tell it to copy.

Comment: @bbum: Thanks for the clarification. I always assumed that pointer value returned by the getter would be thread-safe when atomic+synthesize was used.

Comment: It is safe in that you'll get back something valid. Consider; you have `firstName`, `lastName` and `fullName` (which combines the two) properties.  No amount of `@property` atomicity will protect against setting first name, then last name, while 2nd thread calls for full name in the middle of that....